# Redraw datatable with one less column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

My current table has 4 columns and I'm drawing a datatable in it, which works fine.
Now after a button click, I remove first column from that datatable and then I do

```
datatable.clear().draw();
datatable.destroy()
```

before getting new data using ajax call and populating this new table with it.

```
<table class="display dataTable responsive event_table" cellspacing="0" role="grid">
              <thead class="table-heading">
                  <tr class="row-header-table">
                      <th class="name-col">Name</th>
                      <th>Created Date</th>
                      <th>Ending Date</th>
                      <th>Duration</th>
                      <th>Description</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <thead class="table-search hidden-xs">
                  <tr class="row-search-table">
                      <td class="name-col-data"><input type='text' data-column='0' class='search-input-field'></td>
                      <td><input type="text" data-column="1" class="search-input-field"/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" data-column="2" class="search-input-field"/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" data-column="3" class="duration-slider"/></td>
                      <td><select data-column="4" class="form-control description-list"><option value="">All</option></select></td>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                  <tr class="row-header-table">
                      <th class="name-col">Name</th>
                      <th>Created Date</th>
                      <th>Ending Date</th>
                      <th>Duration</th>
                      <th>Description</th>
                  </tr>
              </tfoot>
          </table>
```

Jquery code to remove first column -

```
$('.name-col').remove();
$('.name-col-data').remove();
$(".event_table tbody td:first-child").remove();
```

But datatable is throwing error message saying that  -

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '4' for row 0, column 4. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

Inside chrome console -

```
datatables.min.js:89 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are able to include your DataTables init script maybe it will help as well but - Is data-column attribute used by DataTables for population? If so, you probably need to reindex it, you probably return one less column in the ajax but it's still searching for element with index 4 (data-column-4).

Comment: I added this code to change data-column every time I remove column ` $(".event-search").each(function(index) { $(this).attr('data-column',index);});`
But it still not working

Comment: An alternative solution to removing the column, is to use the DataTables' API to just hide it. To do that, use `datatable.column(1).visible(false);` = see https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you're getting happens because you have one more column in your table definition than you have in your AJAX result data. That's consistent with the error result that you are getting, which is that by the time you get to the fifth column (starting with 0, of course), you no longer have any fields left in the row to populate it with.

You haven't shared the code that you use to redraw the data table after fetching your data, and you haven't shared the structure of the data you're trying to populate it with, so I can't tell you exactly how you're managing that. But it looks most probable that you have failed to remove the header and footer elements prior to redrawing your data table.

As such, I would investigate two things, both of which would cause this error: whether your calls to `remove()` fail to remove anything, and whether you are trying to redraw the table prior to removing the header and footer elements.

This code line suggests the latter:

```
$(".event_table tbody td:first-child").remove();
```

The selector doesn't match anything in your HTML, since you don't have a `tbody` element in it. This suggests that it gets added when you try to populate your table, as it does in some cases. Meaning, you're trying to remove the column after trying to populate the table.